# Powershell script for XML comparision

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to compare web.config file from production to non production using powershell script. I am able to generate code which can compare upto one level but beyond that I didn't find any help over internet to compare and update xml file with multilevel deep node structure. Below is my code which works upto first level in the file but not beyond. Is there any way I can compare two file and update without hard coding any node element? Below is my code which works upto one level.

```
$src_web_config = "C:\Users\live\web.config"
$dst_web_config = "C:\Users\int\web.config"

# Creating XML objects for live and integration
$src_xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$dst_xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$src_xml.Load($src_web_config)
$dst_xml.Load($dst_web_config)

# get top nodes
$src_top_node = $src_xml.DocumentElement.Name
$dst_top_node = $dst_xml.DocumentElement.Name


function add_node($add_node)
{
    Write-Host "Node", $add_node.name, "doesn't exist"
    $node = $dst_xml.importnode($add_node, $true)
    $dst_xml.$dst_top_node.appendchild($node)
    $dst_xml.Save($dst_web_config)
}

if ($src_top_node -eq $dst_top_node)
{
    if ($src_xml.$src_top_node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        $src_xml.$src_top_node.ChildNodes | % {
            if ($dst_xml.$dst_top_node.ChildNodes.name -contains $_.name)
            {
                if ($_.haschildnodes)
                {
                    #nothing I can find                    
                }
            }
            else
            {  
                add_node($_)   
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Regards,
Vj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a [XML Diff and Patch Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx) that you can use in a .NET application. Microsoft also provides a sample [GUI Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx) written in C# that uses the library. You can download the GUI source code installer from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24313).

I don't have any particular advice on using the XML Diff library from Powershell. Using .NET libraries from Powershell is a whole other topic, but you can find information on it online. If you are not committed to Powershell, perhaps you could use C# or VB.NET instead, as in the GUI Tool. If you don't need to write your own script to automate the process, you can use their GUI Tool to diff XML files on an as-needed basis.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lithis. Working first time on windows stuff. Can you tell me in which language this tool is written? Can I use it directly in powershell script?

Comment: @Vijay The XML Diff library is a compiled .NET library. The GUI tool is written in C#. You can probably use it from Powershell, but I have not tried it. I have updated my answer.